# iPhone dev noob question: Invoking action explicitly on application launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

I just started getting into iPhone development. I have been mish-mashing tutorials and material from books in order to get my bearings straight. I come from a PHP and Java background... Objective-C is a bit quirky. But, I learn best by getting my feet wet.

Basically, I have these actions. getPhoto is bound to a couple of UIBarButtonItems in my view.

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIBarButtonItem *) sender == choosePhoto) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    theimageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

My goal is to invoke the same action once the application launches, automatically opening the Camera. How would I go about this?

Comment: In my self appointed role as interface nazi I have to ask: Will your users expect the app to open to the camera? The first time they use it will it be readily apparent to them why the camera popped up? Unless your app is named "Take Picture" or something equally evocative, jumping straight the camera can cause confusion.

Comment: Also, the method is not bound to the actions. Binding has specific meaning in the Apple API and its important long term not to confuse it. If you think of the method as bound to the buttons your in for a world of confusion. Instead, the buttons are sending a message to the object  in the form of action method call. The action in IB merely tells the button what object to target and what message to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355798/how-to-launch-iphone-camera-on-viewdidload) you should actually place it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

---

Add a similar method to the `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` method in the app delegate.

Might be better to place the call in the `ViewDidLoad` of your root view controller

Comment: Like this? [self getPhoto];

Or how?

Comment: Well yeah, you don't want to use sender from the app delegate though.  You might need to alter your existing method or launch one similar since sender in this case will be the app delegate

Comment: see edit and the answer from jm below.  In this case the viewDidLoad method is probably more appropriate

Comment: have you put `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in the header file of your app delegate?