# can i open camera on onload of application using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to launch iPhone Camera on viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355798/how-to-launch-iphone-camera-on-viewdidload)

I am trying to open the Camera UI on start of my application. The thing is, i have already done the camera app with a start button where on click of that start button, the camera is opened and used to capture photos and videos.

I am trying to call the startCameraControllerFromViewController from the viewDidLoad method but i am facing the following exception

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController: self
                                    usingDelegate: self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1355857/525576 should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably would be better off putting your code in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method. My guess is that even though the view has loaded it may not actually be visible yet, and the startCameraControllerFromViewController call may not like that.

Just a guess.